# Using a Drupal module in a multiuser environment

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have seen some Drupal modules ([Drupal Rooms](http://drupal.org/project/rooms) and [Hotel Booking System for Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel)) that offer the functionality I want but only to the site admin.

I am new to Drupal but would like to be able to offer the ability to add rooms (available for booking) to all registered users of my website. Is this type of thing possible in Drupal with permissions or will I have to effectively rewrite/modify one of these plugins?

Comment: usually it could be found in the permissions page, try visiting the exact url of the addroom-page with a registered user account after setting proper permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally possible in Drupal, my advice would be to create a role for the users you want to be able to add rooms and then visit the permissions page to assign that role to the appropriate permission. It might take a bit of searching but trawl through the permissions page and you'll find the right one(s).